# How to connect to a host webserver when using virt-manager and qemu?

Tags: networking, qemu, virt-manager

I have an `archlinux` machine setup a `Windows 7` virtual machine using `qemu`. `Network Source: NAT/ Device Model:virtio` is the networking configuration for `NAT`ing. I am able to connect to the Internet just fine.

However, how do I connect to the `host` machine itself using IP? Actually, I want to access the webserver running in the host machine on multiple ports!

I tried opening the `ipconfig`'s `gateway` which is `192.168.122.1` but that is not connecting to the `nginx` I am running on my `host`. For example `http://192.168.122.1` doesn't bring up the `nginx` nor another webserver I run at another port. `tracert` is also not helping me much.

Indeed `192.168.122.1` is the `vibr0` in my host and this is the `gateway` of the `virtual machine`.

Comment: Specify your distribution and version!  On Fedora, you have to enable the port in the firewall.

Comment: After a connection attempt, `ip neigh` on the host should show an entry, for the IP address of the VM.  (You can probably use `ip -4 neigh`, if you're not using a v6 address).

Comment: Depending on your configuration your host's address is the same as the default router (e.g. 192.168.122.1, if you did not modify).

Comment: @sourcejedi, pardon my ignorance but on the host of client side!

Comment: Firewall would be on server (nginx) side. I guess you'd remember if you had one on arch :).  `ip -4 neigh show dev virbr0` on host after connection attempt please, and/or `tcpdump -i virbr0` during.

Answer (score 2):

`virt-manager` needs firewalld.service to be up and running in the host machine. This will disable all the ports from external access by default. So we need to explicitly enable the ports that need to be accessed in the host machine. Assuming you want to enable the port `8000`, here are the commands you need to execute in the host machine:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8000/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

[Here](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-open-a-port-in-centos-7-with-firewalld/) is the source of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use `firewall-config`, the GUI for `firewalld`, which handles editing rules and making them permanent, so I don't have to worry about it. I highly recommend it.

I simply had to do one thing:

- Go into the zone named `libvirt` in the Firewalld GUI.
- Go to the "Ports" tab.
- Add a port, such as `tcp 5000`.

Now my virtual machine can connect to the host machine's IP on port 5000. :)

This technique ensures that the port only opens on the virtual machine's network, not all networks!

You can use the host machine's normal ethernet IP when connecting to it from the guest, by the way.